# Python learning environment

Tags: python, django, pylons, activepython

I'm looking to get up to speed on **Python**:

Is it worth working locally via the **ActivePython interface**, then progressing to a website that supports one of the standard frameworks (**Django** or **Pylons**) OR utilize the **Google Apps environment**?

I want to stay as interactive as possible - making feedback/learning easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with the Python interpreter. Take one of the tutorials that many people on SO [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+tutorial) and you're on your way. Once you're comfortable with the language, have a look at a framework like Django, but not sooner.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean.

For development

First choice: idle -- you already have it.

Second choice: Komodo Edit -- very easy to use, but not as directly interactive as idle.

For deploying applications, that depends on your application.  If you're building desktop applications or web applications, you still use similar tools.  I prefer using Komodo Edit for big things (either desktop or web) because it's a nice IDE.

What are you asking about?  Development tools or final deployment of a finished product?

Answer (score 2):

I learned using the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and IDLE (with shell).  Go to Django well after you fully understand Python.

Answer (score 1):

I would just start locally. Django and Pylons add another layer of complexity to the edit/feedback loop.

Unless your primary focus is to make python websites, just stick with an editor and the console.

Answer (score 0):

ipython and your favorite text editor. spend an hour with these screencasts and you'll be comfy with it in no time.

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=CnluURUTV

Comment: I am getting "Server error - server <IP4> is unreachable at this moment."

Comment: yeah sorry I wasn't able to predict that a source I was citing would be available 13 years into the future.

Comment: Don't worry, such things happen unfortunately. But what I learned from it is to put some more info from the link target into the answer so that it is still useful when the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need both - an **IDE** (= Integrated Development Environment) for hands-on experience and then also **learning material** (tutorials with learning chapters and examples) - here's what I recommend based my own experience:

### 1. Python IDE's

**[PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)** from JetBrains has a nice all in one IDE and it welcomes you with a very good tutorial regarding the usage of the IDE (code completion, IntelliSense etc) based on simple Python examples when you installed it and run it for the first time.

It is interactive, because it explains each step for each topic and lets you try it. Then it checks if you have done it right and gives hints if not.

There is a **Community Edition (free)** available for download or you can buy the Professional version or have it via subscription.

---

**[Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/)** from Microsoft has also Python integration.

You can choose between a **Community Edition (free)**, or you buy Professional or Enterprise. You can also have an [MSDN subscription](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/msdn-platforms/), then you can always download the latest versions with no extra costs.

There are some template projects available (web projects, Django etc),  but starting with it is not so easy as it is with PyCharm, since in Visual Studio there is no interactive tutorial for first use available.

---

The standard IDE coming with Python is of course **[IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html)**, its latest version can be [downloaded here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

However, if you just **need an editor supporting Python Syntax**, then look for [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). All of them are free. For quick experiments with Python, there is also [pythonfiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com/fiddle/) or [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/live.html) available.
With [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/live.html) you can even visualize the execution graphically.

All of these apps / tools mentioned are free.

---

---

### 2. Python Tutorials

Then for the **[Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm) language** and **[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/overview/)** you can visit the following websites to start:

- in English:

  [www.python.org/about/gettingstarted](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)  - for beginners

  [www.learnpython.org](https://www.learnpython.org/)  - beginners & advanced

  [www.w3schools.com/python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/)  - beginners & advanced

  [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/) - Django tutorials & documentation

  [Writing your first Django App](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/) - Django step by step

  [RealPython.com](https://realpython.com/) - Various useful topics

  [Writing a wrapper for C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-python-wrapper-for-c-sharp-methods-using-reflection/) - call C# methods from Python

  [Computer Graphic - Mandelbrot set](https://realpython.com/mandelbrot-set-python/#making-an-artistic-representation-of-the-mandelbrot-set) - Create Mandelbrot sets with Python
- in German (use "translate to english" in your browser's context menu):

  [www.python-lernen.de](https://www.python-lernen.de/)  - beginners & advanced

Note that usually those learning sites have lots of examples you can directly try out with the IDE's mentioned above.

I am sure there is a lot more out there, but the learning sites mentioned above are free.